# Vortordo - kvantadverbo ne rekte apud «da»

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, word-order

Ĉiuj komprenus tiun frazon.

> Mi havas multe da X.

Sed ĉu ankaŭ tiu havus sencon?

> Mi multe havas da X.

Kaj ĉu ankaŭ ambaŭ el tiuj ĝustas?

> Ĉu da X? Mi havas multe.
> Ĉu da X? Mi multe havas.

La kvantadverbo devus rilati al la "da X", sed kiom gravas vortordo, tiuokaze?

Comment: "Ĉu da X? Mi havas multe." povus okazi en interparolado (se oni ne bone audas la ikson). La respondo tamen verŝajne komenciĝus per "jes": "Ĉu da X? Jes, mi havas multe.".

Comment: Mi rimarkas ke vi malfotege akceptas respondojn, aŭ komentas eĉ kiam oni rekte demandas al vi. Tio ne tro emigas klopodi ilin respondi... Espereble tiuj antaŭaj respondoj kaj komentoj de la komunumo tamen utilis al vi.

Comment: Mi pardonpetas. Preskaŭ ĉiuj respondoj ja utilis al mi. Mi ne konsciis ke mi forgesis agnosi tiom da respondoj. Mi ĵus akceptis la respondojn, kiuj estas plej utila laŭ mi, sed kelke da tiuj havas pli ol unu bonan respondon, kaj do estas malfacile elekti nur unu por akcepti.

Comment: En ordo! kaj dankon pro la akceptitaj respondoj. Tio okazas ankaŭ al mi, kelkfoje malfacilegas akcepti nur unu inter bonaj respondoj... Oni ne estas devigata akcepti tamen, mi plurfoje vidis komentojn de la demandinto fine de ĉiuj bonaj respondoj klarigante tion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sed ĉu ankaŭ tiu havus sencon?

> Mi multe havas da X.

Jes. Apartigi `multe` kaj `da` per verbo, kvankam vere neofta vortordo, ja estas sencohava. Jen du Zamenhofaj ekzemploj el Tekstaro:

```
Estas nekredeble, kiom multe ekzistas da homoj pli aĝaj

Ankaŭ tre multe estis da bruloferoj
```

Pli da detaloj pri tia uzo vi trovos en: [nekutimaj uzoj de `da`](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/da/nekutimaj_uzoj.html).

> Ĉu da X? Mi havas multe.

La vorto `da` kunligas kvantan vorton kaj objekton, `da + X` ne povas memstari, vi bezonas la kvantan esprimon. En dialogo, tio *povus* (iel streĉite) funkcii jene:

```
Ana - Ĉu vi havas multe da X?

(forta bruo malhelpas la komprenon de la vorto X)

Klaus - Ĉu [multe] da X? Jes. [Mi multe havas] / Jes. [Mi havas multe]
```

Notu ke Klaus ne elizias la vorton `multe` pro gramatikaj kialoj (tio estus malĝusta), li simple reprenas la frazon ekde la loko kie li ĉesis aŭdi. Aliokaze `multe` (aŭ alia kvanta esprimo) estas deviga.

En la respondo `Mi multe havas` ne bezonatas, ĉar jesa respondo al ĉua demando jam enhavas tiun informon, kiun vi tamen povas emfazi per ripeto.

Gramatike vi bezonas mencii **kaj** la kvantan esprimon **kaj** `X`, se vi uzas [`da`](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/da/index.html).

Comment: Parenteze, la ekzemplo "Da pulvo ni havas kiom vi volas." de tiu ligilo al PMEG estas ruza rimedo por kurtigi "tiom da pulvo, kiom"! Kvankam nekutime, estas laŭ mi fojfoje utile tiel reordigi "da X".

Comment: Senrilate, denove estas du bonaj respondoj! Mi trovas la vian pli rekta por respondi la demandon, sed ankaŭ tiu de Juha aldonas sufiĉe bonan informon.

Answer (score 1):

Rigardu la prepozicion "da" kiel montrilon de la [partitivo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitivo), ke ĝi montras parton de io. Tio estas la kutima uzo de la prepozicio "da". Ekzemple

- *Mi aĉetas du litrojn da lakto.*

kie la ideo estas, ke estas nedifinita kvanto de lakto, el kiu vi aĉetas parton. Nature estas subkomprenita supra limo, la kvanto, kiu estas en la vendejo en la momento de via aĉetado.

Kvankam estas lingvoj, en kiuj oni uzas la partitivon ĉiam, kiam ne eblas kompletigi agon dum la tempo, kiun la tempo de la verbo esprimas, kaj logike la akuzativo montras, ke oni kompletigas la agon dum tiu tempo, Esperanto uzas la akuzativon ambaŭsence:

- *Mi legas libron* : povas esti, ke mi legas la libron ĝis la fino dum nuna legado aŭ ke mi nun legas nur parton de ĝi

Eduardo Trápani jam referencis PMEG-on pri nekutimaj uzoj de la "da". Notinda estas la paragrafo pri "da-ismo" kaj ties noto:

> Eventuale oni povus akcepti esceptokazajn uzojn de memstara *da* post vortoj, kiuj ne estas per si mem kvantaj, se tio helpas eviti miskomprenon.

kun la ekzemplo

> Mi volas skatolon da. = Mi volas tiom, kiom enhavas skatolo.

kontraŭ

> Mi volas skatolon. = Mi volas tian ujon.

Sume la kutima uzo de la prepozicio "da" montras partan objekton. En la neŭtrala vortordo la da-esprimo tuj sekvas la kvantan esprimon, sed aliaj vortordoj estas eblaj por emfazo. Eventuale akceptita nekutima uzo estas tiu, en kiu oni uzas nekvantan substantivon por montri kvanton.

Kiel do nekutimaj uzoj, kiujn oni ne akceptas laŭ PMEG? Verŝajne pro influo de mia denaska lingvo mi estas preta akcepti la sekvan dialogon, sed nur en klara kunteksto:

- Ĉu vi volas havi kafon?
- Jes, kun lakto kaj sukero. Multe da lakto, mi petas.
- Kaj ĉu da sukero?
- Ne multe, dankon.